# Crop image in codeigniter (save a specific part of the image)

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I want to implement crop image functionality in codeigniter, actually I want to show a box on the image so that user can move it and save the specific part of the image. Can anybody help please, where to start from?

Comment: Read docs and find examples for PHP GD library. I used it a lot, can't remember specifics.

Comment: Some clues: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?450336-Select-area-of-an-image